# React problems when I try to make an API call using fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I have a problem I try to make an API call to https://randomuser.me/api/ using fetch and I try to `setState` my value array to the API data and then to map and I can't figure out where is the problem in my code because I get some errors.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ value: data }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>test</p>
        <div className="map">
          {this.state.value.map((item) => (
            <p>{item.gender}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: "i get some errors" Can you be more specific? What do you intend for your code to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: Is `data` an array or items you want to put into an array?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/t0y9jo here is a photo with errors and i want to dissplay the gender from this api

Comment: i want to put content from that api inside the value from this.state

Comment: try setting value to `data.results`

Comment: worked thanks but can you explain better why should i do this? thankssss

Comment: The randomuser api is giving you an object with 2 properties: results, which is the array of users, and info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint you are fetching from sends the response as an object, when you try to `setState` with the call `this.setState({ value: data })` it sets the entire response object as `this.state.value`. That is why you get the error `"this.state.value.map is not a function"` because `this.state.value` was replaced as an `object` by the `setState` call.

I believe you want the value of `results` property from the response object which has the correct array data for the user. You can simply change the `setState` call to set the value as `data.results`.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ value: data.results }));
  }
```